# Numpy - get multiply difference between neighboring elements

Tags: python, numpy, diff

Is there a function that returns an array with the results of dividing the next element by the previous one?
Like a "diff()", but with dividing

Not-numpy-example:

```
t=[1,3,6,24,36]
t1 = [j / i for i, j in zip(t[:-1], t[1:])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign `t` to a numpy array:

```
t = np.array(t)
```

Simply divide:

```
>>> t[1:] / t[:-1]
array([3. , 2. , 4. , 1.5])
```